# Impressão em impressora matricial, em rede, com PHP

Tags: php, windows, impressora

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo txt simples para a impressora em rede. O servidor é Windows, php 5.6 e está em uma VPS. A impressora está configurada por VPN.

Já tentei instalar a dll php_printer, mas o PHP não reconheceu a biblioteca.

Se eu envio via CMD, utilizando o comando abaixo, funciona:

Get-Content "arquivo.txt" | Out-Printer \rede\impressora

Porém, executando este mesmo comando via exec no PHP, não vai. Já tentei utilizar systema, passthru, etc.. nada funciona.

Alguém tem alguma luz para este caso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Qual seria o resultado de:
exec('Get-Content "arquivo.txt" | Out-Printer \rede\impressora 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output); ?

Comment: Apareceu array();

Comment: Fiz desta forma, pode ser que contenha algum erro.
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$impressora = "SCX-3400";
$comando    = "Get-Content mapa.txt | Out-Printer $impressora";

exec($comando, $output); 

print_r($output);